# Trouble with CSS Link Positioning

Tags: css, xhtml

I'm experiencing an issue with my CSS when working in Firefox.  It should be pretty simple.  Everything is working fine except that I cannot seem to get the links in the header aligned to the right (the color will change as well as any other modifications except alignment).  The only way I can do it is to float it right, but that reverses the order of the links and seems wrong.  Maybe there is a better way to deal with the links in the header than the span that I've used?  I will have some more links in the header in another position, though, so I need to specify which links I'm referring to somehow...

Take a look at the code below:

First, the HTML:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "layout2.css";</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="all">
<div id="head">
<span class="headlinks">
<a href="#">Logout</a>
</span>
</div>
<div id="menu">
</div>

<div id="content">

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>"
```

Now, the CSS:

/* Layout2.css */

```
#all {
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.headlinks a {
    text-align:right;
        color:#ffffff;
}

#head {
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color:#336699;
}

#head h1 {
    margin-top: 1%;
    text-align:right;
}

#menu {
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1%;
    top: 12%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 90%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    background-color:#b1b2a3;
}

#content{
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 12%;
    width: 72%;
    height: 90%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change `<span class="headlinks>` to a `<div>`, and add `text-align: right` to its CSS style.

Comment: Just tried changing it to <div id="headlinks"> and in the CSS changed it to:

#headlinks a {
 text-align:right;
 color: #ffffff;
}

and this upset the containers - everything was all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
#head { text-align: right; }
```

The head div is a block element with 100% width. Headlinks is an inline element containing one link. `text-align` is used on a block element its contents, not on inline elements to indicate how to place them inside their parent.

An alternative approach is to make headlinks a block level element:

```
span.headlinks { display: block; text-align: right; }
```

Which to use depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't want all of the text in the header to be aligned to the right...just these particular links.

Comment: adding {display:block;} is just what i was missing, thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Actually, there is now another issue. When I add additional links to this line they now show up on several lines instead of on the same line.  How do I get multiple links to be next to eachother on the same line using this method?

Comment: @Tony: put the second link inside the same span.

Comment: @cletus: I put three links in the same span:

<span class="headlinks">
<a href="###">My Account</a><a href="##">Users</a><a href="#">Logout</a>
</span>

The browser puts a line break after each one - but they are all aligned right. I'd just like them all on the same line.

Comment: This is the CSS for headlinks: 

.headlinks a {
 display:block;
 text-align:right;
 color: #ffffff;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the 'text-align:right' on the 'head' div rather than the 'headlinks' span. This style applies to block level elements like div, not inline elements like span.